# Phrase order: A house (is being built by them) (next door to our school)

Tags: difference, sentence-structure, adverbs

I was reading an article and I found this:

> A house is being built by them next door to our school.

If I say

> A house next door to our school is being built by them.

Would it make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, and effectively mean the same thing. They are not entirely equivalent, in that the version in the article indicates *where the house is being built* whereas your proposed alternative indicates *where the house will be located*; but in practice, houses are nearly always built on location, so barring some clarification to the contrary, readers of either version will infer the same set of facts.

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely write it either way, but the meaning is slightly different.

The first, "A house is being built *by them* next door to our school" stresses "by them" as opposed to the house.  Perhaps you might use this in the context where you were already talking about them, and were bringing up the fact that they had this other project.  You're really discussing them, and not the house *per se*.

The other example, "A house next door to our school is being built by them" is a little tougher to evaluate as far as where the stress is, but it stresses the house much more strongly than the first example does.  I might expect to see this construction when you were discussing them building something else somewhere else, but now wanted to communicate that this other project was a house instead (or perhaps, in the context of knowing they often don't do houses, that they're doing two houses right now, one which you already discussed, plus this one by the school).

The differences are subtle, and to be honest, I would expect most people who speak English as a second language wouldn't use those subtleties, but from a native speaker, I would certainly interpret the sentences with these slight differences.  Context - what else has been said before and immediately surrounding what they are saying - will certainly guide you more closely into knowing what they mean.